# Why the in the ListView_ItemCommand event does not trigger on URL-Rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, listview, url-rewriting, itemcommand

The `ItemCommand` of the `ListView` object triggers great, without `URL Rewriting`, (powered via [urlrewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html))

```
Private Sub ListView_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView.ItemCommand

End Sub
```

With the URL ReWritting turned-on the event does not trigger.

Could you please point me a trick to make them both work?

Comment: please add more details in this like which code-block is not working out. Also `Page.ResolveUrl` might solve your problem regarding css/js/image.

Answer (score 1):

The URL Rewriting may be interfering with the postback.  Take a look here for a potential solution: http://ruslany.net/2008/10/aspnet-postbacks-and-url-rewriting/

Also, try adding the following to your page_load event handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
}
```